# Call getAccounts or getAccountsByType for our own app without GET_ACCOUNTS permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-account

My app already acts as an authenticator, and I just want to check whether a specified account, whose type belongs to my app, already exists.

We can create a new account using `AccountManager#addAccountExplicitly` without the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission, can we check whether an account created **just** for our app exists without that permission?

Comment: i don't think so, since you need to check data of account which if it is connected to your app or not, you need permission

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAccounts()), it turns out that all flavours of `getAccounts()` require you to hold the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission, so short answer to your question is no.

Comment: `Clients of this method that have not been granted the GET_ACCOUNTS permission, will only see those accounts managed by AbstractAccountAuthenticators whose signature matches the client.` - this seems to contradict this?